# Using DetachedCriteria Subquery with innerjoin

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

This is the sql query that I'm trying in Hibernate.

```
     Hibernate: select this_.pName as y0_, this_.kNum as y1_, count(*) as y2_ from ALL_CPView this_ inner join ALL_AMView aID1_ on this_.agentid=aID1_.AgentID 

        Criteria crit = statelessSession.createCriteria(APRecord.class, "apr")
            .createAlias("manageID", "ID", Criteria.INNER_JOIN);
 crit.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("PName"), "PName")
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("kNum"), "kNum")
            .add(Projections.rowCount() , "count"));
    results =  crit.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(APStat.class)).list();
```

Now I'm trying to write a DetachedCriteria Subquery, but it's not working. What I have so far:

```
                DetachedCriteria pCrit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(APRecord.class);
                crit.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("agentid", pCrit.setProjection(Projections.property("agentid"))));
        projList = Projections.projectionList();
        projList.add(Projections.countDistinct("agentid"));
        crit.setProjection(projList);
```

Can someone tell what am I missing? Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is not working? CPU rejects to execute instructions? Or you get an exception?

Comment: I get null back. No results.